# Why won't my android service that plays music work?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm relatively new to android development and I'm trying to make a game in Android Studio where I want background music to play. Here is my code for the service:

```
public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = null;
    MediaPlayer player;
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.backgroundmusic);
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(100,100);

    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return 1;
    }

    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TO DO Auto-generated method
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {
        player.pause();
    }
    public void onPause() {

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        player.pause();
    }
}
```

And in the activity where I want to initialise the backgroundmusic

```
Intent svc=new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
startService(svc);
```

which is placed in the onCreateMethod. When I open the activity where I call the service to play the music, nothing happens, total silence.

For some further details: the backgroundmusic file is in a .mp3 format and the phone on which I do my testing is a Nexus 6 running the latest version of Marshmallow.

I'm probably missing something obvious, can anyone point it out for me and/or give any tips on how to do it better in the future? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a prepare-Listener:

```
player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.d(TAG, "preparation Completed ...playing ");
        player.start();
    }
});
```

I think the setVolume is by default handled with a float (0=off, 1=max). Check your log output too. Sometimes the MediaPlayer is reporting a error-code.

**EDIT / Second approach:**

Did you added this line to your manifest (inside application tag)?

```
<application
    ... >
    <service android:name="BackgroundSoundService"  android:enabled="true"></service>
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, sadly, that doesn't work either. I have also set my audio back to 1f, 1f an checked the log output, nothing shows.

Comment: The strange thing is. That the audio player is started if it is prepared within the onStartCommand method. It still doesn't play. Which I think suggests that the player isn't even prepared. Which I don't seem to understand.

Comment: Make a log output if .isPlaying() returning true. I also would recommend to look at Androids Core Media Formats: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core

Comment: You can use the free software Audacity to convert your mp3 to an ogg file. Maybe your mp3 file does not conform the official specification.

Comment: The problem is not the media file, when I just set a mediaplayer on the first page to play the music, it plays the music perfectly, even if I close out of the application or go to another activity. The reason I don't just use this is that the .setLooping(true) doesn't work. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing.

Comment: Look at the answer again.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm such an idiot for not including the service in my manifest.

Answer (score 0):

try this piece of code for running the music on the start up

```
public class start extends Activity {
MediaPlayer intro;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle Start) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(Start);
    setContentView(R.layout.start);
    intro =  MediaPlayer.create(start.this,R.raw.SONGNAME);
    intro.start();
    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent openStart = new Intent("com.example.main.MAIN");
                startActivity(openStart);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    intro.release();
    finish();
}
```

and make sure that the music file is located in the correct folder (raw)

Comment: Thank you for the help, my sound is indeed in the raw file. The only thing is that this restarts an activity, which screws with the user experience.